# Cakephp Login page access

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I am wondering how any user can get access to login.ctp, even if the user not logged in. In the function beforeFilter(), I see
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
    $this->Auth->allow('add', 'logout');

So, access is granted without authentication to index, view, add and logout. I checked both the controller and its parent controllers, but do not see any there that says provide access to this function or page: /users/login

Thanks.

Edit: I know that login page is required to log into the application and before we are logged into, but my question is how does it know that this is the login page and it needs no security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a login function in your controller which renders the `login.ctp` view then in `beforeFilter` call `$this->Auth->allow('login);`

Answer (score 0):

`$this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');` is for the methods in the controller and not the views. You can display the login.ctp view in any method call by using `$this->render('login')`. I would check to see if the index method is using the login.ctp file. Beyond this, I would need more information to know how to properly answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The auth component allows access to the login action by default.

See **[https://github.com/cake.../2.5.6/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php#L307](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.6/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php#L307)**

It doesn't really know what plugin/controller/action is used for logging in until you tell it via the `AuthComponent::$loginAction` property, respectively the `loginAction` option in the component configuration, however it uses `/users/login` by default.

See

- **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent::$loginAction**